# Python join with comma is printing only the keys, not keys with values

Tags: python

I need to concatenate a list of key value pairs with comma in between each item.  Meaning that if I have a dictionary like this:

```
{A:0,B:0,C:1}
```

I need to have an output like:

```
A0,B0,C1
```

without spaces.

I have written this piece of code, but it is only printing the keys of the dictionaries. It is not printing the values.

```
weights = {'A':0, 'B':0, 'C':1}
for each in weights:
    weights[each]= 1
logs = ",".join(weights)
```

Output I'm getting:

```
A,B,C
```

Output expected:

```
A1,B1,C1
```

I've have tried to put `weights.keys()` and `.values()`, but then I don't know how to put those together.

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Try: `for key, value in weights:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionaries usually iterate by keys.  And the order is arbitrary.  For the output you're seeking, you may prefer to sort and iterate the item pairs like this:

```
>>> ','.join('{}{}'.format(k,v) for k,v in sorted(weights.items()))
'A0,B0,C1'
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the way Python dictionaries behave when iterated over. To get the behaviour you want do:

```
logs = ",".join(key + str(value) for key, value in weights.items())
```

Also, if only need it for debugging you can just print the result of `weights.items()`.

Answer (score 3):

To relate it to your code:

```
d = {'A':0,'B':0,'C':1}

s = []
for k, v in d.items():
    s.append("{}{}".format(k,v))

print(','.join(s))
```

Then, you can ultimately shorten that to one line:

Pay attention to the fact there are no square brackets here. We are actually using a generator expression here, which is more efficient than making a list comprehension in this case.

```
print(",".join("{}{}".format(k,v) for k, v in d.items()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries are key,value pairs. For the expected output you need to have both :

```
','.join('{}{}'.format(k,v) for k,v in sorted(weights.items()))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `weights.items()` to get the key-value pair, and then join them.  Then, join those joins with a comma.  It can all be done with a list comprehension:

```
>>> ",".join("{}{}".format(*items) for items in weights.items())
A0,B0,C1
```

This way, you could change your mind later and decide to put a colon in there, for example:

```
>>> ",".join("{}:{}".format(*items) for items in weights.items())
A:0,B:0,C:1
```